# How manually enter data in excel plots?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

[image: to]

I want to enter raw data into excel plots just by typing the numbers 20.35,20.35 but excel doesn't allow this by default and only accepts data from cell references. How to do it my way?

Comment: type: `={20.35,20.35}`

Comment: https://www.excelforum.com/excel-charting-and-pivots/665994-manually-enter-x-y-range-data-to-series-values.html

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it is possible to assign data other than Cell references to plot the Chart in Excel.**

**How it works:**

- From **Insert Tab** click any of the Chart type Icons.
- You get blank Chart plot area.

[image]

- Now, click **Select Data** from the menu.
- From the poped up dialogue click **Add** button.

[image]

- Fill Data as shown above in Sceen Shot.

  `={15,22.50,45.99,98}`

*Note,* Series Name is an optional.

- Finish with **Ok**.

*Now you get the Chart.*

[image]

**N.B.** This method has been used with Excel 2013 & 2016.